# What does it mean in HTML "The attribute in no namespace"?

Tags: html

I was wondering what does it mean `The attribute in no namespace` can some one give an explanation on what it means?

Comment: Let's see some code. What are you attempting to do that is giving you this error?

Comment: @Kohan its not an error I wanted to know what does The attribute in no namespace for example `The lang attribute (in no namespace)`?

Comment: Can you give some more context?

Comment: Need more detail than what is given. Sounds like you haven't declared a namespace for your document.

Comment: A namespace is used to stop conflicts in your code. For example, if you were to use any of the HTML tags, a namespace can determine what context the tag is used in. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_%28computer_science%29#XML_namespace

Comment: -1 for wasting people's time with a hazy question, and not clarifying after repeated requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a namespace is used in xhtml, or more general xml,
when a tag has a namespace it looks like

```
<namespace:elementname/>
```

namespaces sometimes have to be defined in the xml/xsl/etc

note: in some xml editors (fe. firefox) you dont see the namespaces - so go for the source, plain data ..

Comment: Not really. In XML, the bit before the colon is the `prefix`. The prefix is a reference to the namespace - not the namespace itself. So `<a:mytag xmlns:a="mynamespace"/>` and `<b:mytag xmlns:b="mynamespace"/>` are elements in the same namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The lang and xml:lang attributes

The lang attribute (in no namespace) specifies the primary language for the element's contents and for any of the element's attributes that contain text. Its value must be a valid BCP 47 language tag, or the empty string. Setting the attribute to the empty string indicates that the primary language is unknown. [BCP47]

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/elements.html

Comment: A conceptual space that groups classes, identifiers, etc. to avoid conflicts with items in unrelated code that have the same names; To categorize by placing into a namespace
en.wiktionary.org/wiki/namespace

Comment: Sorry but im shooting in the dark kinda. Still not sure what you need to know exactly, if you elaborate in your question you will be more likely to get a meaningful answer. Either that or i'm being dumb. I'm never sure.